# Reach a database file online

Tags: java, database, server

I'm working on a javaprojekt on the university. we will build a communication tool.
we have a firebird database file and we want to reach it online.

I'm using this solution on my local project.

```js
        String rel = "/HOGDB.FDB";
        
        File tempFile = new File("");
        String absoluta = tempFile.getAbsolutePath();
        
        String databasen = absoluta + relativa;

        try {
            db = new InfDB(adress); 

        } catch (InfException e)
```

I have a web host using Cpanel with ftp and something they call web disk.

Can I work with the file online like I do local?
Are web disk the way to go?

```js
    try {
            Socket server = new Socket("www.myserver.com", port);
            DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
            InetAddress adress = server.getInetAddress();
            System.out.println(adress);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Webbserver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

with this code I can connect to the server but how can I reach the file and work with it?

thanx a lot!
/mats

Comment: What is a "webbhotell"?

Comment: Swedish for web host  

Comment: Are you using Java or JavaScript? The second code snippet looks more like Java.

Comment: @Tim I think he is actually using Java, not Javascript

Comment: @Nosrep Indeed, the tag has been updated =)

Comment: Have a look at http://css.insttech.washington.edu/~lab/Support/HowtoUse/UsingJDBCWithFirebird.html